# ASP.NET MVC Ajax.BeginForm doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function loginOK()
    {
        var item = document.getElementById('statusLabel');
        item.innerHTML = "OK";
        document.getElementById('LoadImg').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    function process()
    {
        var lab = document.getElementById('statusLabel');
        lab.innerHTML = 'Checking...';
        lab.style.color = 'Black';
        document.getElementById('LoadImg').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }

    function fail()
    {
        var lab = document.getElementById('statusLabel');
        lab.innerHTML = 'Login is being used';
        lab.style.color = 'Red';
        document.getElementById('LoadImg').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
</script>

 <div style="width:30%; float:left;">
     <label for="Login">Login:</label>
     <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Login) %>
     <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Login) %>

     <img id="LoadImg" alt="" src="../../Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
     <br />
     <label id="statusLabel" />
     <br />
     <%=Ajax.ActionLink("CheckLogin","CheckLoginAvailability", "Account",
        new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "statusLabel", OnBegin = "process", OnFailure = "fail", OnSuccess="loginOK"})%>
 </div>
```

and, in the AccountController:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public void CheckLoginAvailability(string login)
    {
        //do some job
    }
```

And, FireBug says that /Account/CheckLoginAvailability is not found. Also, after callback that ActionLink is hidden. Why ?

Comment: I was wrong; actions can return `void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about `Ajax.BeginForm` in your question but this is nowhere to be seen in the markup you provided. There are a couple of issues that I can see with your code:

1. Your action method doesn't return an `ActionResult`. Yeah I know, you will say that this is possible, right, but that's against any good practices, conventions and rendering your controllers unit-test friendly.
2. You are using Microsoft Ajax which will mix markup and javascript which IMHO is bad for multiple reasons: increasing bandwidth which of course leads to decreased performance, incapacity to externalize javascript into separate files in order to cache them by client browsers, having to write things like `document.getElementById`, `innerHTML`, `style.color`, `style.visibility`, etc... which is not guaranteed to work cross browser.

Here's what I would suggest you to improve this. While this doesn't answer your question, take it as an alternative approach.

As always the first thing to deal with is to define a model which in your case might look something like this:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
}
```

Of course you might wish to add other fields such as `Password`, but this is out of scope for the moment. The next step is to write a controller dealing with this model (in parallel you should be already setting a unit-test for the future controller to prepare the ground):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Simply return the Login form
        return View(new LoginViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        // Deal with the actual authentication, etc...
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckLoginAvailability(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        // TODO: query your datasource to determine whether 
        // model.Login is taken
        // For this purpose we will suppose that it is taken
        bool isLoginTaken = true;

        // return a JSON object containing the result
        return Json(new { IsLoginTaken = isLoginTaken });
    }
}
```

The last part is to paint the screen:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SomeNs.Models.LoginViewModel>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Login</title>
    <!-- Use a separate CSS to avoid mixing markup with styling -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%: Url.Content("~/content/site.css") %>" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Always use HTML helpers when dealing with Urls -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content("~/scripts/login.js") %>"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <%: Html.LabelFor(x => x.Login) %>:
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Login) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Login) %>
        <br/>
        <!-- Always use HTML helpers when dealing with Urls -->
        <img id="loadImg" alt="" src="<%: Url.Content("~/content/images/ajax-loader.gif") %>" style="display:none;" />
        <br />
        <div id="statusLabel"></div>
        <br />
        <!-- Give this link an id so that we can easily identify it from javascript -->
        <%: Html.ActionLink("CheckLogin", "CheckLoginAvailability", "Home", null, new { id = "checkLogin" })%>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

And the last part is to unobtrusively attach our javascript (using jQuery of course) in the `login.js` file:

```
// When the DOM is ready
$(function () {
    // Attach a click handler to the checkLogin link
    $('a#checkLogin').click(function () {
        // When this link is clicked send an AJAX POST request
        // to the address this link is pointing to
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: this.href,
            // Pass as parameter in the POST body the login
            // entered by the user
            data: { login: $('#Login').val() },
            beforeSend: function () {
                // show the spinner image before sending any AJAX request
                // to inform the user of an ongoing activity
                $('#loadImg').show();
            },
            complete: function () {
                // hide the spinner image when the AJAX request completes
                // no matter if it succeeded or not
                $('#loadImg').hide();
            },
            success: function (result) {
                // if the AJAX request succeeds
                // query the IsLoginTaken property
                // of the resulting JSON object
                if (result.IsLoginTaken) {
                    // Show the status label with red if the login is taken
                    $('#statusLabel').html('Login is being used').css('color', 'red');

                } else {
                    // Show the status label in black if the login is not taken
                    $('#statusLabel').html('OK').css('color', 'black');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: As I remember, there were always problems for me with Ajax.BeginForm (the same code worked different) so the second thought was to use jQuery. Your code looks very interesting, I'll check it. Thanks :)

Comment: Everything works fine, but why after success the input is hidden ? Even if I write success: {... $('#checkLogin').show();} it doesn't show

Comment: Notice how the `statusLabel` is declared in my code: `<div id="statusLabel"></div>` instead of `<div id="statusLabel" />` or  `<label id="statusLabel" />`. I think this could make a difference.

Comment: wow, it resolved the problem. I didn't realize that it could made the difference

Comment: @Tony, while this resolves the problem I cannot really explain the technical aspect of it. Maybe someone more experienced with jQuery and the DOM could shed more light.

Answer (score 1):

As @SLaks says actions can return void but, I think the action signature is such that it is required to return an action result and you can return `EmptyResult` if you don't want to return anything.

see this http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-controller-overview-cs

try changing your AccountController to

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult CheckLoginAvailability(string login)
{
   //do some job
   return new EmptyResult();
}
```